# How to name the temperature sensors instead of printing address using ds2482-100 and ds18b20 sensor- Help

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, arduino-ide, i2c, ds18b20

I am using 10 ds18b20 Temperature sensors using with "DS2482-100" I2C board and Arduino
so when I am getting the output like this:- "ROM = 28 46 04 1F 0D 00 00 74 96014B467FFF0A100A 25.3 2699 Dc", so Instead of address I want to name it "Sensor-1", "Sensor-2"  like that any tutorial or help would be appreciated.

1. `*
   Arduino library for controlling DS2482-100 and DS2482-800 1-wire masters.
   Uses Wire library to communicate with DS2482 so be sure to call Wire.begin() before using the library.
   Quick example modeled after Onewire example:
   */

   ```
    #include <OneWire.h>
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <DS2482.h>
    #include <DallasTemperature.h>

    DS2482 ds(0);  //channels ds2482-800 is 0 to 7, DS2482-100 is just set 0

    byte data[12]; //holding for onewire capture
    byte addr[8]; //1wire wire address and CRC
    long time_temp;

    uint8_t sensor1[8] = { 0x28, 0x00, 0xF9, 0x1E, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x76 };
    uint8_t sensor3[8] = { 0x28, 0x61, 0x64, 0x12, 0x3F, 0xFD, 0x80, 0xC6 };

    void setup()
    {
       Wire.begin();
       ds.reset();
       pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

       // start serial port
        Serial.begin(57600);
        time_temp = millis();
    }

    void loop()
   {

      //do search

     if ( !ds.wireSearch(addr))
     {
       if(addr == sensor1)
       {
       Serial.print("sensor1");
       };
    Serial.print("No more addresses.\n");
    ds.wireResetSearch();

   return;
   }

   Serial.print("ROM =");
   for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   Serial.write(' ');
   if (addr[i] < 16) Serial.print("0");
   Serial.print(addr[i], HEX);
   }

   if (ds.crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
   Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
   return;
   }

   //test if device code DS18b20
    if (addr[0] == 0x28) {

    //read temperature data.
     ds.wireReset();
     ds.selectChannel(0);
     ds.wireSelect(addr);
     ds.configure(0x05); //set bus on strong pull-up after next write until next command
     ds.wireWriteByte(0x44); //convert temperature on this device
     delay(770); //wait for conversion 750ms Plus margin
     ds.wireReset();
     ds.selectChannel(0);
     ds.wireSelect(addr);
     ds.wireWriteByte(0xbe);         // Read Scratchpad command

     //display hex values of scratchpad
     Serial.print(" ");
     for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
     {  

      data[i] = ds.wireReadByte();

     if (data[i] < 16)Serial.print("0");
     Serial.print(data[i], HEX);

   }
     Serial.print(" ");

     //convert to decimal temperature

       int LowByte = data[0];
       int HighByte = data[1];
       int TReading = (HighByte << 8) + LowByte;
       int SignBit = TReading & 0x8000;  // test most sig bit
       if (SignBit) // negative
   {
       TReading = (TReading ^ 0xffff) + 1; // 2's comp
   }

       int Tc_100 = (double)TReading * 0.0625 * 10;

       if (SignBit) // If its negative
   {
       Tc_100 = 0 - Tc_100;
   }

     //print temp for each device

      Serial.print(Tc_100 / 10);
      Serial.print(".");
      Serial.print(Tc_100 % 10);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(millis() - time_temp);
      Serial.println(" Dc");
      }


      }
   ```

Comment: You've almost done it - but you can't compare one array to another as you would compare two ints. Instead you have to compare them byte by byte and test that both byte[0]s match, both byte[1]s match, ..., etc until you reach the end of the arrays. Some languages support comparing or doing arithmetic and array transformations on an entire array with a single statement. C++ doesn't support that.

Comment: Like JRobert said, it's not a feature of the language.  It is, however, available to you in a couple of ways on the ESP8266.  The C library (and therefore C++) has [`memcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp), which will compare sequences of bytes.  The ESP8266 also comes with a fairly complete C++ standard library, including [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal), which can be used to compare arrays of anything that supports `==`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, I am trying it with 2 sensors,since I am new to this programming I am unable to write it correctly, and moreover I want to use it for 10 or more than 10 temperature sensors in that case is it possible to use memcmp(). Thank you